# C: Using CR in a file

Tags: c

I am trying to put ','  and '\n' in a file. All values are 0 , except 4, 9, 14, 19, 23...  where I am putting ','  and '\n'

But the output is coming:

> 0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,

What I am expecting is :

```
0000,0000
0000,0000
0000,0000
0000,0000
0000,0000
```

and so on

This is a sample code I have written. 
What is wrong here?

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    finalascii[i ]='0'; 
}

int g=0;

for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    finalascii[i+4 + g]=',';
    finalascii[i+9+g]='\n';
    g=g+4; 
}
fwrite(finalascii,  100, 1, fpw);
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. And format&indent the code properly!

Comment: i  have written '\n', but here it becomes '\r'

Comment: It was the edit of @selbie. I rolled back. Next time **your** format the code **yourself**.

Comment: `'\n'` is a line feed; not a carriage return.

Comment: You are trampling over the end of your array, by a factor of about 4*100.

Comment: @Jongware we haven't been told the size of the array

Comment: @M.M: true. Then make that: you're writing way beyond the end of that `0`s sequence. (Unless this is not *all* code OP wrote and somewhere before or after that zero-fill he already filled the (purely hypothetical) rest of the arrays with zero characters as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unrolling your loop (i.e. filling in the values of `i` and `g`), we find that your loop makes the following assignments:

```
i[ 4] = ',';
i[ 9] = '\n';
i[ 9] = ',';
i[14] = '\n';
i[14] = ',';
i[19] = '\n';
i[19] = ',';
i[24] = '\n';
```

and so on. The result of this is that you build the string `0000,0000,0000,0000...` . There are no `'\n'` because you immediately overwrite each `'\n'` with a comma.

Also, your loop ends up with:

```
i[499] = ','
i[504] = '\n'
```

But you only initialized `100` places with `0` in the first place, so this suggests you haven't correctly implemented whatever you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you write three fields, like so:

```
0000 0000 0000
```

... and then for some reason you decide you want to change the separators. You do so by writing a comma at the first separator, then a newline at the second separator... Then you iterate onto the second iterator and replace it with another comma.

Do you see what's wrong with this picture? You're overwriting the `'\n'` you want to write with a comma. Perhaps you meant to write `g = g + 9;`?